# Apache .so and .c files

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I see what there is checks for mod_rewrite.c file in different .htaccess files, but i have only mod_rewrite.so, what is the difference between them?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Make sure directory listing is disabled
Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes
RewriteEngine on

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds kind of backwards but that's just the way it works. The [`<IfModule>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#ifmodule) container wants either a module name or a module file. In the case of the module file, it wants the source file (.c). This is because some modules are *compiled into apache* so there is no shared library file (.so).

In the case of [`LoadModule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_so.html#loadmodule), which loads a module that is external to the main apache core, you use the .so file.