# mod_headers module does not load, though it's enabled in httpd.conf

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-headers

I need `mod_headers` to force download of a file depending on GET parameter.

```
  <FilesMatch "*.gif">
     <If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /dl/">
        #Download header
        Header set Content-Disposition "attachment"
     </If>
  </FilesMatch>
```

Code above produces an error 500. However, if I wrap it properly in `<IfModule>`, it does not do anything at all:

```
<IfModule mod_headers>
  <FilesMatch "*.gif">
     <If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /dl/">
        Header set Content-Disposition "attachment"
     </If>
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

This makes me think that `mod_headers` didn't load at all. But I have it enabled in `httpd.conf`:

> ...
>   LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
>   LoadModule headers_module modules/**mod_headers.so**
>   `#`LoadModule heartbeat_module modules/mod_heartbeat.so
>   ...

Is there any debug log to find out what mods have been loaded and what not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for the `mod_headers.c` module:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
```

(See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19610847/851273) about the .so/.c stuff)

But the reason you're getting the 500 error is twofold.

First, the `<FilesMatch>` container expects a regular expression, and "*.gif" isn't a valid regular expression. You probably just want to use the `<Files>` container.

Second, the `<If>` isn't available in apache 2.2, only version 2.4. If you aren't using apache 2.4, then you're not going to be able to use the `<If>` container.